# Handling Special Font Styles in Node.js with fabric.js JSON Data

Tags: node.js, fonts, fabricjs

Is there a way in Node.js, similar to how browsers handle it, to apply special font styles (bold, italic) to text in images generated from fabric.js JSON data, without explicitly importing those specific font style variants?

Body:
I'm working on a front-end template editor using fabric.js and integrating it with a Node.js backend. The front-end generates JSON data using fabric.js, which I then manipulate on the backend based on API parameters to control the content of the image template.

Issue:
In Node.js, when processing fonts, I encountered an issue. If I only import regular fonts without special styles (like bold or italic), the generated images do not reflect these special font styles as specified in the JSON data. In contrast, in a browser environment, it's possible to change font styles using CSS, even if only the regular font is imported.

What I've Tried:
I've successfully generated images using regular font styles.
Attempted to apply bold and italic styles through JSON data, but the output does not reflect these styles.

Code Example:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    { registerFont } = require('canvas');

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'font');
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir)
files.forEach((file) => {
    registerFont(path.join(dir, file), { family: file.split('.')[0] })
})

var jsonData = {/* JSON Data Omitted for Brevity */};

// Create an instance of fabric.Canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas();

// Set canvas dimensions
canvas.setWidth(jsonData.width);
canvas.setHeight(jsonData.height);

// Load JSON data into fabric.Canvas
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonData, function () {
    canvas.renderAll(); // Render fabric.Canvas to Canvas context

    // Convert fabric.Canvas to Base64-encoded image data
    const imageDataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'png', multiplier: 1 });
    const base64Data = imageDataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
    const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

    fs.writeFileSync('output.png', buffer);
});
```